# What happens if you try to receive from a Timer channel again after it has expired

Tags: go

I'm playing around with one of the [examples](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/6) from the Tour of Go tutorial. I've edited the code as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    tick := time.Tick(100 * time.Millisecond)
    boom := time.After(500 * time.Millisecond)
    for {
        select {
        case <-tick:
            fmt.Println("tick.")
        case <-boom:
            fmt.Println("BOOM!")
            c, ok := <-boom
            fmt.Println(c)
            fmt.Println(ok)
        default:
            fmt.Println("    .")
            time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("Finished")
}
```

However, the output of the code is as follows:

```
    .
    .
tick.
    .
    .
tick.
    .
    .
tick.
    .
    .
tick.
    .
    .
tick.
BOOM!
```

`c` and `ok` are never printed, and the very last "Finished" is never printed either. Can someone help me understand what exactly happens when I try to receive from the `boom` channel the second time?

Comment: `c` and `ok` are never printed, because nothing else is ever sent over the `boom` channel. It's pretty straight forward. Did you expect otherwise? If you want to reuse it, you must [Reset](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer.Reset) it.

Comment: @Flimzy but in that case wouldn't receive block forever? How does the program terminate?

Comment: I don't understand your question. As it is, your receive blocks forever, because nothing is ever sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what time.After does (quote from [go docs](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#After)):

> After waits for the duration to elapse and then sends the current time
>   on the returned channel.

So `boom := time.After(500 * time.Millisecond)` will return a channel and send a single message to that channel after 500ms. Now lets consider your code:

```
case <-boom:
   fmt.Println("BOOM!")
   c, ok := <-boom
   fmt.Println(c)
   fmt.Println(ok)
```

When something is received on the boom channel your code prints "boom" and then waits for something else on the boom channel. However only one thing is ever sent to the boom channel so the statement `c, ok := <-boom` will never complete (and your application will never terminate). If you changed boom from a `time.After` to a `time.Tick` then you might see something more like what you were expecting (the application will still run for ever).

The original code is a bit different:

```
case <-boom:
            fmt.Println("BOOM!")
            return
```

It receives the message, prints boom and then returns (ending the program). If you want your code to get to the bit where it outputs 'finnished' then you need something like the code below. Note that the label `loop` is needed [because break](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Break_statements):

> terminates execution of the innermost "for", "switch", or "select"

so without the label break would exit the select but the for loop would continue.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    tick := time.Tick(100 * time.Millisecond)
    boom := time.After(500 * time.Millisecond)
loop:
    for {
        select {
        case <-tick:
            fmt.Println("tick.")
        case <-boom:
            fmt.Println("BOOM!")
            break loop
        default:
            fmt.Println("    .")
            time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("Finished")
}
```

Comment: The thing that is confusing me is that the program *does* terminate. Or at least it does when I run it in the go playground (you can copy/paste my code and try it for yourself?). As far as I understand it shouldn't terminate, which is why I'm confused

Comment: In the go playground it exits with "Program exited: process took too long.". This is because the go playground runs applications within a sandbox which limits execution time (amoungst other things). Without this someone would be using it to mine bitcoin :-). Try running it on your computer and it will not exit.

Comment: Really? For me it exits without any error in the go playground :/

Comment: I copied/pasted your code into the playground at https://play.golang.org/p/dJE9LE1eMNP running that gives me "Program exited: process took too long."